# Returning 1 row using Model_Crud in FuelPHP

Tags: fuelphp

How would I modify this so that it returns a 1 row object, rather than an array?

```
$slot = Model_Slots::find(array(
    'where' => array(
        array('datetime', '=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $s)),
        array('club', '=', $club->id),
    ),
));
```

(Solution at the moment is to follow it with... `$slot = ($slot[0]) ?: false;`, ugh!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both find_by_pk() and find_one_by() return a single model object, like the ORM get_one() equivalent.

The other find methods return an array of results. The easiest is to add a LIMIT 1, and use

```
$result and $result = reset($result);
```

to get the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `get_one()` - http://docs.fuelphp.com/packages/orm/crud.html#/find_chaining

```
$slot = Model_Slots::find(array(
    'where' => array(
        array('datetime', '=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $s)),
        array('club', '=', $club->id),
    ),
))->get_one();
```

Comment: Sorry I’m using Model_Crud, not the Orm – thanks for your answer though, appreciated.